# TEXTFSM Parser to Parse different sections

Tags: parsing, python-textfsm

I have this data that is **NOT** separated by a blank line:

```
show environment power-supply
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Product Serial PSU Input Voltage Wattage
Mbr/PSU Number Number Status Type Range Maximum
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1/1 SL085C TTS22GZ1AAT OK AC 100V-240V 250
1/2 SL085C TTS23GZ2BBH OK AC 100V-240V 250
2/1 SL085C TTS23GZ3CC9 OK AC 100V-240V 250
2/2 SL085C TTS23GZ4DDB OK AC 100V-240V 250
show environment temperature
Temperature information
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Current
Mbr/Slot-Sensor Module Type temperature Status
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1/1-Switch-ASIC-Internal line-card-module 61.12 C normal
2/1-Switch-ASIC-Internal line-card-module 61.00 C normal
1/1-CPU management-module 45.00 C normal
1/1-CPU-Zone-0 management-module 40.00 C normal
1/1-CPU-Zone-1 management-module 40.00 C normal
```

I want to parse different sections of this. The TEXTFSM Parser I have written so far works fine on independent sections but it gives only record one I try to combine it. Can someone help me fix this.

TextFSM Parser:

```
Value List POWER_SUPPLY ((?P<MBR_PSU>^\d+\/\d+)\s*(?P<PRODUCT_NUMBER>\S+)\s*(?P<SERIAL_NUMBER>\S+)\s*(?P<PSU_STATUS>\S+)\s*(?P<INPUT_TYPE>AC|DC)\s*(?P<INPUT_VOLTAGE_RANGE>\d+V-\d+V)\s*(?P<MAX_WATTAGE>\d+))
Value List ENV_TEMP ((?P<MBR_SLOT>^\d+\/\d+)(?P<SENSOR_TYPE>\S+)\s+(?P<MODULE_TYPE>\S+)\s+(?P<TEMPERATURE>[-+]?\d*\.\d+\sC)\s+(?P<STATUS>\S+))

Start
  ^show environment power-supply -> PowerSupply
  ^show environment temperature -> EnvTemp

PowerSupply
  ^${POWER_SUPPLY} -> Start
  ^(?![^-{78}])


EnvTemp
  ^(?![^-{78}])
  ^${ENV_TEMP} -> Start
```

Also guide me if you can with the steps you took for me to understand your approach if it works fine.

The output right now looks like this but I want to capture all the lines in the respective section.

```
[{'ENV_TEMP': [{'MBR_SLOT': '1/1',
                'MODULE_TYPE': 'line-card-module',
                'SENSOR_TYPE': '-Switch-ASIC-Internal',
                'STATUS': 'normal',
                'TEMPERATURE': '61.12 C'}],
  'POWER_SUPPLY': [{'INPUT_TYPE': 'AC',
                    'INPUT_VOLTAGE_RANGE': '100V-240V',
                    'MAX_WATTAGE': '250',
                    'MBR_PSU': '1/1',
                    'PRODUCT_NUMBER': 'JL085A',
                    'PSU_STATUS': 'OK',
                    'SERIAL_NUMBER': 'TTS22GZ1AAT'}]}]
```